# get latest option of multiple select with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

How to get last choosen option in multiple select?

```
$('#select').change(function(event) {
    ...
});
```

I do not need all values provided by `val()`, but LATEST choosen option which triggered `change`.

Thanks

Comment: $('option:selected' ,this).val();

Comment: `this.value` or in jQuery `$(this).val()` will get you the currently selected option's value. I'm confused as to why you think `val()` gives you all values?

Comment: what do u mean by optin in multiple select and how?

Comment: select multiple http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp

Comment: can you add the HTML part?

Answer (score 1):

I fear that you can't have it so easily, even with jQuery. But you can store the old values and compare with the current value.

```
var last = [];
$('#select').change(function(event) {
    var val = $(this).val();

    var newValues = val.filter(function(element)) {
        // You may need a more specific test for your values
        return last.indexOf(element) == -1;
    });

    // newValues are the new selected options in the select

    last = val;
});
```

But WARNING : If the user cancel an option, the `change` event is triggered too. And `newValues` will be empty (because there's no new values, only a missing value).

Comment: this is ok, if there is no more elegant solution